# General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR), How can I generate report of user history

Tags: node.js, azure, sql-server-2016, azure-blob-storage

I am facing an issue of timeout and exception, which will incomplete the task, this is first time implementation this security feature in the application.

Process is :

1. Generate e-mail of history data
2. Delete images from blob storage
3. Delete actual data from DB

What is the efficient and correct way to implement it.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details about how the data is stored. Also tell us at what step you're getting timeouts and exceptions. Also include the exceptions you're getting. As it stands now, the question is not clear.

Comment: I just need to know efficient way to implement this feature, exception and timeout is not my concern.